# Migrate ssrs 2008 r2 to ssrs 2016

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

The current setup of the server is Windows Server 2008 sp1, with SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 r2 installed. The databases are on a separate server which is using SQL Server 2008 r2.

I have a new server with Windows Server 2012 r2, I have installed SSRS 2016 on this server and configured it the same as the original server, restored the encryption keys, and connected to an exact copy of the DB server.

Locally on the new RS server I can access and run the reports using the web interface http://{servername}/reports/. However when I try to access the same url remotely I get redirected to http://{servername}/reports/#/browse, I can see the folders and reports, but when I run a report I get a blank report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if ssrs 2016 does not support IE9. The machine I was using to access the server remotely only had IE9 installed. When I used the IE development tools on the server itself to browse to the site using IE9 standards, I had the same problems.